# unable to parse JSON data from a NSURLConnection response

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services, nsdictionary

I am getting a server response of the form:

```
results are:{
    AverageMark = 40;
    "Grade A" = 10;
    "Grade B" = 20;
    "Grade C" = 30;
    "Grade D" = 20;
    MaxMark = 99;
    MinMark = 44;
    ProfileGrade = "";
    ProfileMark = 1;
}
```

However I am unable to save the response data into an Array.
This is my code inside **didReceiveResponse**:

```
    {    
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:responseData];
        NSArray *jsonResults = [jsonString JSONValue];
        NSLog(@"results are:%@",jsonResults); //this log is shown above
        for (int i=0; i<[jsonResults count]; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *AllData=(NSDictionary *)[jsonResults objectAtIndex:i]; //Program is crashing here--//
            NSMutableArray  *DataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSString *avgMarkString;
            avgMarkString=(NSString *)[AllData objectForKey:@"MaxMark"];
            [DataArray addObject:avgMarkString];
        }
    }
```

I want to save the response data into the array called "DataArray". But the program is crashing.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: try with this : - `avgMarkString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[AllData objectForKey:@"MaxMark"]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't have the complete data yet in `-connection:didReceiveResponse:`. Create an instance variable or property of the type `NSMutableData` and initialize the data ivar or property in
`-connection:didReceiveResponse:` if you get a valid statusCode (between 200-299 should be ok). Use `appendData:` on the data object in the `-connection:didReceiveData:` delegate method. Finally in  `-connectionDidFinishLoading:` the data is complete and can be parsed into JSON.

Alternatively you could just use the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library. The library got some convenience methods for dealing with XML, JSON, images, etc...

Read the following page to get an introduction into the capabilities of AFNetworking: http://engineering.gowalla.com/2011/10/24/afnetworking/

---

Some example code from one of my own projects for downloading using a queue using NSURLConnectionDelegate methods. The URL Request objects are a custom subclass of NSURLConnection for some block "callbacks":

```
#pragma mark - URL connection delegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(200, 99);
    if (NSLocationInRange(httpResponse.statusCode, range));
    {
        self.data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [_data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // inform caller that download is complete, provide data ...

    if (_request.completionHandler)
    {
        _request.completionHandler(_data, nil);
    }

    [self removeRequest:_request];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    DLog(@"%@", error);

    // inform caller that download failed, provide error ...

    if (_request.completionHandler)
    {
        _request.completionHandler(nil, error);
    }

    [self removeRequest:_request];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that isn't json, try having a look at this http://json.org/example.html

Comment: its a JSON response. its printing JSONValue in log

Answer (score 1):

Given JSON response is invalidate. Validate your JSON response [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I have also tried the following: `  NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:responseData];

    NSArray *jsonResults = [jsonString JSONValue];
     NSLog(@"results:%@",jsonResults);
    for (int i=0; i<[jsonResults count]; i++)
    {
    NSDictionary *AllData=(NSDictionary *)jsonString; //using string this time
        NSMutableArray *DataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSDictionary *setData;
        NSString *avgMarkString;
    avgMarkString=(NSString *)[AllData objectForKey:@"MaxMark"];[DataArray addObject:avgMarkString];`

Comment: replace this line : `NSDictionary *AllData=(NSDictionary *) jsonString; with NSDictionary *AllData=(NSDictionary *)jsonResults;`

Comment: I have validated it. Its a valid Json.

Comment: first I tried `NSDictionary *AllData=(NSDictionary *)jsonResults` it was not working

Comment: How did you validate your JSON ?